# Angular ui-router using resolve validate authentication

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to see what's the best way to validate if a user is authenticated into the application.

Right now I'm using the following:

1. The user log in into the application
2. On Server Side a Token is created and send it back to the browser
3. On Log In Success, **AngularJS** stores the **Token**: `$http.defaults.headers.common['RequestVerificationToken'] = token || $cookies.token;`
4. On every http call to the server the **Token** is sent and is verified server side, in case the token doesn't exist then a **401** response status is sent to client.

This is working pretty well, now Im using UI-Router to control application states (pages - real scenario):

I have the following state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('personinfo', {
      url: "/personinfo",
      controller: 'PersonController',
      templateUrl: "app/partials/personinfo.html"

    })
```

Inside my PersonContoller:

```
app.controller('PersonController', function ($scope,$sce, $location, PersonService) {

    $scope.title = 'Person Page';

    PersonService.getPersons().success(function (response) {
        $scope.persons = response.success;
    }).error(function () {
        // If token doesn't exist, a 401 reponse status is sent by server
        $location.url('/login');
    });

});
```

I don't really like how it works because **AngularJS** will load the state and download the partial HTML file and then it will go into the controller and execute the get method and if the token is not valid then it will redirect to **login state**.

I would like to validate the token before the state is being loaded, so if the token is not valid then the partial HTML won't be downloaded or whatever.

I have read that UI-Router has a resolve property that can be used to get data before the view is loaded... can I use the resolve to validate the Token?

Hope someone can give me a guide or advice.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Found this: http://www.bfcamara.com/post/66001429506/authentication-in-a-spa-with-angular   Will try to see if this works

Answer (score 0):

Your build stack should compile production JS with template embedded, so there
is no round trip to worry about.

If you really want to intercept the initial page load, experiment with
`$locationChangeSuccess`, which is fired before the first `$routeChangeStart`.

If you want to hook into resolve, just attach a promise to it.